# Create and Delete Availability Test using Azure SDK C#

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

Cannot find a way how to create or delete Availability Test with C# Azure SDK. I don't see anything in the fluent SDK and traditional either. I've managed to create Availability Test programmatically by using ARM template and running it with C# code.

Unfortunately, no clue how to delete such resource. Any advice?

Comment: do you mean `Application Insights Availability Test`?

Comment: Hello, if my answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer, as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? thanks:).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `Application Insights Availability Test`, then there is a `preview package` for Application Insights management: [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights).

After installing this package:

**To create Availability Test**, you can follow [add a new web test](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/applicationinsights/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights/tests/ScenarioTests/WebtestsTests.cs#L40) to create it.

**To delete Availability Test**, you can follow [delete web test](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/applicationinsights/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights/tests/ScenarioTests/WebtestsTests.cs#L96) to delete it.

I didn't test the code above, but if you encounter any issues, please let me know.

**Another way** is that you can use the [Web Tests rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/webtests) to create or delete it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is an SDK (not fluent) which allows to perform several operations over Application Insights and Availability Tests (Web Tests). The nuget is called `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights` (currently version `0.3.0-preview`).

It has quite nice way to delete Web Test but when it comes to creating WebTest it requires in the web test configuration a XML which seems to be not that elegant solutions as some might expect.

Anyway, it's doable with some SDK to make it programmatically.